# How Do I Further Group a Time_Bucket Query by a Non-Aggregate Column (an ID String)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Let's consider a table with 3 columns: ID, Timestamp, and Values to be aggregated.

I am attempting to query the database using SQL such that I have rows grouped by the ID, and aggregates then orders the Values based on the binner Timestamp values. As an example, the output would look something like:

| ID | TimeInt | AValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12:00 | 13 |
| A | 12:01 | 17 |
| A | 12:02 | 15 |
| B | 12:00 | 62 |
| B | 12:01 | 69 |
| B | 12:02 | 84 |
| C | 12:00 | 59 |
| C | 12:01 | 56 |
| C | 12:02 | 63 |

The code I've been working off of (seen below) aggregates and groups Values by binned Timestamps, but dissolves differences between IDs, leaving me with fewer rows than I require (3 in this case). All values that share the same timestamp bin end up aggregated.

```
SELECT 
    time_bucket('1 minute', Timestamp)  AS TimeInt,
    avg("Value")        AS AValue
FROM source

WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN '12:00' and '12:02'
AND "macId" IN ('A',
'B',
'C'
)
GROUP BY TimeInt
ORDER BY TimeInt
```

Given that I'm trying to both select and group by a non-aggregating text column, I've been having a lot of trouble finding where exactly to edit this query to get the right output. I've tried finding methods to mix aggregate and non-aggregate columns, such as using JOINs, or OVER() and PARTITION BY, but none of the solutions also include the use of TIME_BUCKET. I'm still a general SQL Novice, so I would greatly appreciate any help.